# Add array of post id's to a category?

Tags: customization, functions

Is there a function to add array of post id's to a category,something like this array(2,3,5,6)
to put in some category,not looking for update post.
Tnx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly *add array*, but you can loop through that array and run [`wp_set_object_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms) on each post id. Just study function's arguments carefully, because it defaults to overwriting terms, rather that adding.

Comment: I know for that function,but I was hoping that there is a wp builtin function for putting array of post id's to category.Tnx for response.

Comment: @user1147 - What do you mean *"putting array of post id's to a category?"*

Comment: @Mike: I understand the question as a request for an efficient method that adds multiple posts, identified by their post ID's, to a given category. Currently you have to loop over the array yourself and call `wp_set_object_terms()` multiple times.

Comment: @user1147: If you are talking about a lot of posts, it might be worthwhile to temporarily suspend the update of the term count, by calling `wp_defer_term_counting(true)` at the beginning of your operation and `wp_defer_term_counting(false)` at the end.

Comment: @Jan Fabry - I don't know why that wasn't obvious, thank for clarifying. Maybe I should stay away from WA when I'm bleary eyed and badly in need of sleep. :)